# Why is my resource pack not showing up in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm running the latest 1.16 Android version of Minecraft Bedrock under Linux using the mcpelauncher.  I want to create my own custom paintings, so I tried to download some and install them so I could see how it was done.  However, when I unzip the downloaded file to `~/.local/share/mcpelauncher/games/com.mojang/resource_packs/pack_name` it does not show up.  I have tried both under settings (global resources) and for a specific map.  Both files I found were advertised as being 16x16 - I have read that some larger images may require additional work to get them up and running so I thought this would be the most simple.  I also read that it's possible that different versions of Minecraft have different resource pack formats.  Both packs I downloaded were advertised for "Minecraft 1.16" although I don't know if there are any other non-Android/Bedrock versions with this same number.

The format of the unzipped directory is a pack.mcmeta containing pack_format 5, as well as a pack.png and an assets folder containing the actual resources.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is a mismatch between the requirements for Java and Bedrock edition RPs. The `pack.mcmeta` file is for JE, while BE uses `manifest.json`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/documents/resourcepack for more information on creating BE RPs.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation that I have been able to find on this is incomplete and unclear.  But it appears that for a resource pack on Minecraft Bedrock to show up, at least on Android, there must be a manifest.json file in `resource_packs/<name>` and in the folder under `textures/painting` there must be a single kz.png file of a special format.  There is a "Vanilla" resource pack that can be downloaded, I followed the "downloading the example pack" link from the "[Creating Add Ons](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Creating_resource_pack_add-ons)" page.